# Не работает метод onload

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь добавить **HTML** элементы с сервера на **HTML** клиент в ф-ции `getCards`.

Сначала пыталась добавлять без метода `onload`, но выдает ошибку

```
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

//БД
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

//инициализация глобального окружения
global.document = new JSDOM(this.html).window.document;
global.window = new JSDOM(this.html).window;

async function getCards() {
    await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json.data);
        const cardsData = json.data.map(el => {
            return `
                <div class="col col--hidden" >
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="${el.avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${el.first_name} ${el.last_name}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${el.email}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        console.log(cardsData);
        
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log('Global is loaded');
            document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML = cardsData.join('');
        }
    });
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
    await getCards();
});

server.listen(3000, (err) =>{
    if(err){
        throw Error(err);
    }
    console.log('Server is runnig');
});
```

**HTML client**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Business Cards</title>
    <style>

        html {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .col--hidden {
            display: none;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        }
        .row {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 250px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .card-group {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .col {
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        #img {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        .loadMore {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Business Cards</span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="card-group justify-content-center">
        <div id="cards" class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="loadMore"> Load More </a>

    <footer>
        <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
            © Nimchenko Anastasiya 2021
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(function(){
                $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(".col--hidden").slice(0,3).slideDown().removeClass('col--hidden');

                    $(this).toggle();
                })})
        });
        //$(document).ready(JSONToCSVConvertor(cardsData));
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @yar85 я в самом начале объявила global.document = new JSDOM(this.html).window.document;

Comment: А, не, я ошибся - `window` и `global.window` суть одно и то же (следование правилу "никогда не используйте глобальные переменные" имеет свои негативные последствия ). Но вот смысл делать такое через JSDOM после отправки ответа из html-файлика, в функции которая ничего не возвращает и не выводит никуда кроме консоли... по-прежнему неясен.

Comment: @yar85 хорошо, как тогда можно избежать ошибки " Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null "?

Comment: Наилучшим способом избежания такой ошибки, считаю переписывание этого кода под корень: убрать всю непонятную йогу с JSDOM, и вместо нее использовать шаблон (с последующей отправкой отрендеренной разметки ответом на запрос). Для начала использования шаблонов, см. [эту краткую статью](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) в документации экспресса. Шаблонизаторов для ноды существует множество, то есть не обязательно именно pug использовать (который в статье чисто для примера). Попробуй воспроизвести пример с шаблоном, и думаю что сразу поймешь насколько это удобнее.

Comment: @yar85 понятно, но а если не перепичывать весь код, то как избежать ошибки?

Comment: А ошибку не надо избегать, [потому что ее попросту нет](https://runkit.com/yar85/60f82ae8c30ea6001a9675b6)... Так что код все же придется отлаживать и переписывать, т.к. непонятно что у тебя ломается (может проблема в значении `this.html`, а может еще в чем-то другом, "а может быть, а может, ..."). И учитывая необходимость переписывать... см. предыдущий комментарий :)